# select one element from dropdown remove from other dropdowns JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple drop-downs with same options. My code works fine when  the user selects the first item of drop down lists then the item is deleted for the second and third drop down lists. Similarly this occurs for second drop down list. But the problem occurs when I am first selecting the item of second drop down list. Automatically the first drop down list goes blank if I modify my code to include all removal combinations in the drop down jquery onchange() event. My code is:

```
$('#skill1').on('change', function () {
    var n = $("#skill1 option:selected").text();
    var index = $('#skill1').get(0).selectedIndex;
    $('#skill2 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
    $('#skill3 option:eq(' + index + ')').remove();
});

$('#skill2').on('change', function () {
    var p = $("#skill2 option:selected").text();
    var index1 = $('#skill2').get(0).selectedIndex;
    $('#skill3 option:eq(' + index1 + ')').remove();
});

$('#skill3').on('change', function () {
    var r = $("#skill3 option:selected").text();
    var index2 = $('#skill3').get(0).selectedIndex;
});
```

Please help so that the code can extend when selection of any item is made in the drop down list the changes are reflected in the other drop down lists

Comment: So when you select an option in any of the drop-downs, you would like the corresponding option to be removed from the other two drop-down menus?

Comment: yes I want the corresponding option to be removed from other two dropdown menus

Comment: Well you're missing the remove command from the other `on change` functions? Also you're setting variables for `n`, `p` and `r` but you don't seem to be using them? What are they for?

Comment: Actually I tried with other remove commands but when I remove from the second dropdown list the first dropdown list becomes empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this approach can give you some ideas:

1- Add a class to each select so that you can get an array of all them.

2- Add a change event to the elements that contain the class: whenever they change, iterate over the array and remove the option that contains the selected text. In order to prevent erasing options from the select that triggered the event or previous ones (as I think, is your intention) put a guard (startRemoving) that prevents erasing anything from any select previous to the one that triggered the event.

```
var $combo = $(".combo");
$combo.on("change", function () {
    var select = this,
        selected = $("option:selected", this).text(),
        startRemoving = false;

    $combo.each(function (_, el) {
        if (el === select) {
            startRemoving = true;
            return;
        }

        if (startRemoving) {
            $("option", el).each(function (_, el) {
                var $el = $(el);
                if ($el.text() === selected) {
                    $el.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It's only an idea. You can see it working in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mx6ggrph/)

**UPDATE**

If you want changes to get reflected always, just remove the guard and just check that you're not updating the element that triggered the event (the behaviour is a bit weird though):

```
var $combo = $(".combo");
$combo.on("change", function () {
    var select = this,
        selected = $("option:selected", this).text();

    $combo.each(function (_, el) {
        if (el !== select) {
            $("option", el).each(function (_, el) {
                var $el = $(el);
                if ($el.text() === selected) {
                    $el.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mx6ggrph/1/)

Comment: The code is working fine but when I select the option from second dropdown the change is not getting reflected in the first dropdown. Also backward change is not happening that is when we select an option from third dropdown menu the change is not reflected in first or second dropdown

Comment: @tendo Hi, I thought you want it that way. I've updated the question with combos whose changes affect the rest of the combos (except the one that triggered the event). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that is an option for you, but you may want to think about using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) here, as this seems to be a prime example for it. There you could define all your options as an array inside the scope and as soon as something changes all dropdowns will automatically update.

Have a look at that [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mg2x4e6/3/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options = ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]
}
```

That would be the scope then.

Comment: Thanks Yeah its solving the problem. I will go through Angular JS documentation then